# Mastermind Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Im currently working on an assignment of mastermind mini game on python, but
for the code below, when i try to run it, it shows that the first line of my if statement ":" invalid syntax, but in previous lines i had something similar too but that didn't face any problem

```
     while True:
        try_again = str(input('Do you want to try again?[Y/N]: ')
        if try_again.lower() == 'y':
            print('Alright ', user_name, " let's try again!")
            break

        elif try_again.lower() == 'n':
            break

        else:
            print("Sorry, I don't understand, please type Y/N")
            continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the previous line

```
try_again = str(input('Do you want to try again?[Y/N]: '))
```

You forgot an `)` at the end to close `str()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to close a bracket on the line above. Try this:

```
 while True:
    try_again = str(input('Do you want to try again?[Y/N]: '))
    if try_again.lower() == 'y':
        print('Alright ', user_name, " let's try again!")
        break

    elif try_again.lower() == 'n':
        break

    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand, please type Y/N")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the parentheses on the second line. corrected code:

```
     while True:
    try_again = str(input('Do you want to try again?[Y/N]: '))
    if try_again.lower() == 'y':
        print('Alright ', user_name, " let's try again!")
        break

    elif try_again.lower() == 'n':
        break

    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand, please type Y/N")
        continue
```